# Passing a SQL parameter collection to a function

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

When writing ASP.NET CRUD applications in C#, I often find myself inserting a lot of repetitive boilerplate codes for fetching SQL Server queries into data tables, fetching scalar values from queries into variables, calling stored procedures, and so forth.

Recently, I've been trying to refactor this by creating generic classes and methods to handle these basic tasks. However, in order for these to work properly, they need to be able to take an arbitrary number of parameters. The built-in `SqlParameterCollection` class seemed the obvious first choice, but unfortunately this class cannot be instantiated from user code. The next option was to pass a `List<SqlParameter>` to the function, and then use `foreach` to add its contents to the built-in parameter collection of the `SqlCommand`. This worked, but the declaration is a bit clumsy.

To create the list in code before calling the function, I have to do something like this:

```
List<SqlParameter> ParameterList = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Parameter1", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = InputVariable1 },
    new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Parameter2", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = InputVariable2 },
    new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Parameter3", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = InputVariable3 }
};
```

This is hard to read on smaller monitors and still contains a lot of repetitious boilerplate. So my next step was to create a custom class with an overloaded Add method so that this would not be needed. I've read that it is bad to subclass `List` in C#, so I used `Collection` instead:

```
public class ParameterCollection : Collection<SqlParameter>
{
    public void Add(string    ParameterName,
                    SqlDbType ParameterType,
                    object    ParameterValue)
    {
        // Create the parameter and add it to the list
        SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter();
        Parameter.ParameterName = ParameterName;
        Parameter.SqlDbType     = ParameterType;
        Parameter.Value         = ParameterValue;
        base.Add(Parameter);

        // Done
        return;
    }
}
```

I can then declare a parameter collection like this:

```
ParameterCollection Parameters = new ParameterCollection
{
    // name          type               value
    { "@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar, InputVariable1 },
    { "@Parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, InputVariable2 },
    { "@Parameter3", SqlDbType.VarChar, InputVariable3 }
};
```

My question is this: Is there any **quicker/easier** way to perform this task that I'm overlooking? And are there any potential hidden **pitfalls** or bad practices in the way I'm currently doing it?

Comment: I thought Visual Studio automated the bulk of such operations for you.

Comment: `Parameters.Add` has a bunch of overloads I normally use. Anyway, instead of making a class I would probably make a helper function (with overloads/default values) if I wished to shorten "creating" a SqlParameter.

Comment: This should probably be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Can you not use the Entity Framework?

Comment: @user2864740 or you can use `AddWithValue` to leave it up to PDO to determine the type so its shorter

Comment: @meda: please read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) - I would **not** recommend `AddWithValue` over the other options.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten the .Size SqlParameter parameter. If you don't specify it, SQL Server will generate a new execution plan for every size it encounters, so if you had, say, just three possible presented sizes it could generate 27 execution plans where only one is needed.

Comment: @marc_s interesting article I have to agree that being explicit is always better. thanks for sharing!

Comment: @AndrewMorton: The problem with the Size parameter is that I can't find any documentation that says what you're supposed to use for non-string data (e.g. SqlDbType.Int). I could probably make a reasonably good guess, but not knowing the real answer, I'd rather just let SQL Server do its thing on its own. Is there some MSDN information on this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @JDG1980 I would make a parameter without specifying the size if the data type does not use it, but "For fixed length data types, the value of Size is ignored." ref: [SqlParameter.Size Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, for Decimals, you may need to specify the .Scale and .Precision if you are giving it an SQL `NULL` value. More: [Why bother setting the size parameter of a command object parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037995/why-bother-setting-the-size-parameter-of-a-command-object-parameter).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may have overlooked is that `Add` returns the parameter added, which allows us to set the value in the same statement:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = paramValue;
```

Comment: I've seen syntax like this before, but it doesn't work when I try it. If I do something like List<SqlParameter> ParameterList = new List<SqlParameter>(); ParameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = InputVariable1; it results in an error (Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type void).

Comment: @JDG1980 the reason the example in your comment doesn't work is that `List<T>.Add` [has a `void` return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx). And some `SqlParameterCollection.Add` overloads [return other types such as `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(v=vs.110).aspx). But the overload I showed (the most useful one?) [returns the `SqlParameter` added](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx), which you may want to incorporate in your thinking.

Comment: As indicated previously, the problem with `SqlParameterCollection` is that it can't be instantiated from user code, and therefore can't be passed to a function. I'm trying to get away from having dozens of multi-indented `using SqlConnection(...) { ... using SqlCommand(...) ... } ... }` blocks scattered around my code.

Comment: @JDG1980 Yes, I did see your point about not being able to instantiate `SqlParameterCollection`, but part of my point is that it's possible to simplify the `Add` line to the extent you may just use it as is rather than creating a helper whose call is pretty similar to this `Add` line.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than instantiating and passing a collection—which, as you say, is hampered by `SqlParameterCollection` having no public constructor—you may pass the collection indirectly, by passing the `SqlCommand` itself. Your generic classes and methods may then add parameters to `SqlCommand.Parameters`, removing the need for you to instantiate a separate collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to perform this action.

First:
You must declare the new parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50 //the size of Varchar);
```

Then you add the value.

```
cmd.Parameters["@Parameter1"].Value = paramValue;
```

I prefer to use Dapper extension for such things. It is way easier, the syntax is more readable and overall just love it.
Check the link, you might like what you see:
https://dapper-tutorial.net/